# Nvidia Graphics Card not detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

So I have an Nvidia GeForce 610M on my laptop along with an i7 CPU. Unfortunately, I don't think my Nvidia chp is being recognized. When I go into "About this Computer", only my Intel Integrated Graphics are recognized.

Is there any way to have Ubuntu recognize the chip.

P.S. running `sudo lshw -C display` gives me this:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF119M [GeForce 610M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:e8000000-e9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: Does your BIOS setup have the option to select the onboard video card vs. the add-in PCIe card? If so, please select the PCIe card.

Comment: Have you installed the proprietary Nvidia driver?

Comment: i had same problem.my GPU is Nvidia GeForce.....does this solution applies on my gpu???

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is recognizing your chip. The problem is that your system is using your intergrated intel GPU instead. Intel GPU's doesn't require any drivers at all, they just work. So for a Linux system this is ideal.

If you want to use your nvidia chipset, you will need to manually install the driver. But before your going to install a driver you should be aware of something that may have a very big influence on your graphics setup, Nvidia Optimus.

Nvidia optimus is a technology that controls the use of multiple graphics drivers.

So if you are browsing the internet is switches to your intel gpu for low power.
and when your gaming at high res it switches to nvidia for max preformance.

I suspect that your laptop is using Optimus because of your two diffrent GPU's (Intel and nvidia). Mainly because my own laptop has a similar setup (intel i5 with geforce gt 630m).

Now Optimus is not supported for linux by nvidia, but there is a third party solution that works just fine for me called Bumblebee. to install bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

make sure you purge your system from any half-installed nvidia drivers.

after a reboot you can use your nvidia chipset by:

```
optirun Your_Program_name_here
```

that's about it let us know if this did or didn't work,Good luck!